# javascript, how to get the weight of planets to return the correct weight in 2d array when user enter weight

Tags: javascript

```
function calculateWeight(weight, planetName) {
  // 2. how to return the correct weight once user selects a //planet and  enters weight? 

  var currentWeight = document.getElementById('user-weight').Val;
  var planetWeight = document.getElementByID('output').val;

  for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; planets.length; j++) {
      if (planets[i][j]) {
        console.log(planets[i][j])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You don't seem to be using your parameters. You call document.getElementById and then try to get a non-standard field, which you then never use. Clarify your question if you want to get help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There's no question here, just code. What

Comment: `.val` should be `.value`.

Comment: The inner array should use the condition `j < planets[i].length`

Comment: Why do you need a 2D array to hold information about weights on different planets?

Comment: You should use an object whose keys are the planet names. Each value is the ratio of the gravity on that planet to Earth. Then you multiply the user's Earth weight by the ratio to get their weight on that planet.